# Google OpenSSL's Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: windows-10, openssl

I have received  a Google warning related to OpenSSL version update which suggested Linux based command `$ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"` to check OpenSSL version. I have tried Cygwin and other tools but am unable unable to execute this command on Windows 10. Is there any other way to find the OpenSSL version on Windows?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.  Are you trying to update the OpenSSL package on an Android device?  If you need a Windows OpenSSL binary, just compile from source, the source code is located on the [OpenSSL's website](https://www.openssl.org/source)

Comment: Type `openssl.exe version` and it will miraculously tell you the version of OpenSSL you are running.